# MySQL query to bind parent row values to children rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (greatly simplified):

```
| id | firstName | lastName | parent |
|------------------------------------|
|  1 | NULL      | Smith    | NULL   |
|  2 | John      | NULL     | 1      |
|  3 | Jack      | NULL     | 1      |
|  4 | Jimmi     | Joe      | 1      |
|  5 | Jane      | Doe      | NULL   |
```

And I'm trying to create a query that can return the data like this:

```
| id | firstName | lastName |
|---------------------------|
|  1 | NULL      | Smith    |
|  2 | John      | Smith    | 
|  3 | Jack      | Smith    | 
|  4 | Jimmi     | Joe      |
|  5 | Jane      | Doe      |
```

Basically I want it to include all rows, including parent rows. In all child rows (where parent != NULL) I want it to pick the child field value, unless it it NULL, then it should pick the parent field value. Parent rows are not modified.

I've been trying different setups with different joins, but I can't get it right. Is this even possible?

Comment: I believe you need `LEFT SELF JOIN` with `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Have a look: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Joining parent with id **using the parent as the table 1**, this is because if we put data_2.parent = data.id then it would have joined `incorrectly` and **we would have 3 rows with id 1 instead of 1 row.**
- Once we have the join we just take the first non-null value using `coalesce()` . If the last name is present in the original table then we take that otherwise we use the new one that we create using the join above

**code 1 :**

```
WITH data_ AS (
SELECT  data.*, data_2.last_name as new_last_name,
      
FROM [table name] as data
LEFT JOIN data_2
ON data.parent = data_2.id
)

SELECT
*,
COALESCE(data_.last_name,data_.new_last_name) AS final_name FROM data_
```

**code 2: more direct**

```
SELECT  
data.id, 
data.first_name, 
COALESCE(data.last_name,data_2.new_last_name) as final_LAST NAME
      
FROM [table name] as data
LEFT JOIN data_2
ON data.parent = data_2.id
```

Comment: Thank you! The COALESCE was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @KMK no worries, if it works maybe upvote

Answer (score 1):

you can self join the table with an LEFT JOIN on parent and id

> ```
> SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`firstName`, COALESCE(t1.`lastName`,t2.`lastName`) FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.`parent` = t2.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstName | COALESCE(t1.`lastName`,t2.`lastName`)
> -: | :-------- | :------------------------------------
>  1 | null      | Smith                                
>  2 | John      | Smith                                
>  3 | Jack      | Smith                                
>  4 | Jimmi     | Joe                                  
>  5 | Jane      | Doe
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8602e893ddf48388b73226216a50e743)*